# How to measure free RAM on an Arduino Due in Runtime?

Tags: arduino-due, library, memory

I use [this](https://github.com/McNeight/MemoryFree) Library to measure my free RAM on a Mega in runtime. But this Library does not work on the Due.

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/mpflaga/Arduino-MemoryFree

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mikael Patel in a comment, the library from [Arduino-MemoryFree](https://github.com/mpflaga/Arduino-MemoryFree)
 should do it. A minimal sketch that seems to work on the Due:

```c++
extern "C" char* sbrk(int incr);

int freeMemory() {
  char top;
  return &top - reinterpret_cast<char*>(sbrk(0));
}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.print ("Free memory is: ");
  Serial.println (freeMemory ());
}  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

I'm not totally convinced that this gives the correct figure. The figure returned by the library above for my Uno was too high (2297 bytes).

Comment: It seems to work fine after a call to `malloc()`, which is needed to initialize `__brkval`. I would `return &top - ( __brkval ? __brkval : &__heap_start);` in order to have something that works also when not using `malloc()`.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. After all, not everyone uses `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

```
int freeRAM() {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval;
  int v;
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);
}
```

Comment: The question was about a Due. When I tried your code on my Due I got -28 bytes of RAM, which is hard to believe.